# Unable to copy data from DB2 to Oracle via Java because of different charsets

Tags: java, oracle, character-encoding

I'm reading a column field (char(255)) from a DB2 table via resulSet:

```
String tmp = rs.getString(i);
```

this string is 255 chars long in the table, but when I try to put this value in the Oracle column (char(255)) via an insert statement

```
insertStmt.setString(j,tmp);
```

i get an SQL Exception:

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column "[schema_name]"."[table_name]"."[column_name]" (current: 258, max: 255)
```

I can see that

```
tmp.getBytes("UTF-8").length
```

is 258, because of three "è" characters using two bytes instead of one.

How can I successfully convert/insert this string into the Oracle table?
From Oracle db I can read

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
```

but I'm not being able to handle it on Java side.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to change NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS or widen your target field?

NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS allows you to specify the length of a column datatype in terms of CHARacters rather than in terms of BYTEs. Typically this is when using an AL32UTF8 or UTF8 or other varying width NLS_CHARACTERSET database where one character is not always one byte.

It can be set at session level if not defined at database level.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE
```

Oracle advises to use CHAR explicitly when creating the table.

```
Create table scott.test (Col1 CHAR(20 CHAR),Col2 VARCHAR2(100 CHAR));
```

It will also work when importing or using ‘alter table modify ’.

When accessing columns in PL/SQL, define the variables explicitly e.g.

```
Col2 VARCHAR2 (10 CHAR);
```

Limitations:
The instance or session value will only be used when creating NEW columns.
It's good practice to avoid using a mixture of BYTE and CHAR semantics columns in the same table.

As for maximum width, looking at a typical 3-byte UTF8 character:  if you define a column as varchar2(1333) CHAR and you insert more than 1333 characters, you will still get “ORA-12899: value too large for column”.  In these cases, oracle recommends converting varchar2 to CLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Your column is defined with a [BYTE semantic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref52), you have to switch to CHAR semantic using DDL such as:

```
alter table tst modify (txt varchar2(5 CHAR));
```

Small example:

```
create table tst
(txt varchar2(5));

insert into tst (txt) values('ééééé');
-- SQL-Fehler: ORA-12899: value too large for column "REPORTER"."TST"."TXT" (actual: 10, maximum: 5)
```

Note that the BYTE semantic enables to store only 5 bytes and the insert fails.

```
alter table tst modify (txt varchar2(5 CHAR));

insert into tst (txt) values('ééééé');

1 row inserted
```

The CHAR semantic allowed to store 5 character even if they occupy more than 5 bytes.